# compile wxWidget on Snow Leopard

Tags: wxwidgets, compilation, cmake, osx-snow-leopard

I just downloaded wxWidget source code on my snow leopard machine. The source code is the multiplatform one, so it contains windows and GTK components of wxWidget as well. I'd like to compile the wxWidget source code, but haven't found a good guide yet.

This is my first step to create a multiplatform project, hopefully I would be able to use CMake to generate makefile later on.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Just to clarify, I'd like to build stable release of wxWidget on Snow Leopard, it would be building wxWidget 2.8.x on OS X 10.6.x. I have read the compiling wiki here http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Development:_wxMac#Building_under_10.6_Snow_Leopard
Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using configure/make/make install:

```
./configure --enable-monolithic --enable-universal_binary --disable-shared --with-macosx-sdk=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk
make
sudo make install
```

I just tried this with wxWidgets 2.9.0 and it worked great.

Comment: It works with wxWidget 2.8.10. I'm only using stable release now.

Answer (score 1):

The [wxWiki](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Main_Page) is always a good place for guides, specifically the various [OSX](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Guides_%26_Tutorials#Mac_OS) guides and the extra note [here](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Development:_wxMac#Building_under_10.6_Snow_Leopard) about compiling under 10.6.

It would also be good to note that there have been many changes between the current stable releases and the trunk, specifically much work has been done on a port to Cocoa.

Using CMake is pretty straight forward, just check the FindWxWidgets.cmake file in CMake for instructions, you can also check out the CMake docs (I would give the link but they don't seem to be up right now).

Comment: Unfortunately, the wiki didn't help. thanks for the answers though.